# CMake with Boost 1.62.0: "No Boost libraries were found"

Tags: c++, boost, cmake

Using the following `CMake` code:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.6)
project(TrustLineManager)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")

set(BOOST_ROOT D:/Tools/boost_1_62_0/)

set(Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS D:/Tools/boost_1_62_0/boost)
set(Boost_LIBRARY_DIRS D:/Tools/boost_1_62_0/libs)

set(BOOST_INCLUDEDIR C:/MinGW/include)
set(BOOST_LIBRARYDIR C:/MinGW/lib)

set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS ON)
set(Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED ON)

find_package(Boost
        1.62.0
        COMPONENTS system
                   filesystem
        REQUIRED)

include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(TrustLineManager ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
```

I get this error:

```
Error:Unable to find the requested Boost libraries.
Boost version: 1.62.0
Boost include path: D:/Tools/boost_1_62_0
Could not find the following static Boost libraries:
        boost_system         boost_filesystem
No Boost libraries were found.  You may need to set BOOST_LIBRARYDIR to the directory containing Boost libraries or BOOST_ROOT to the location of Boost.
```

What should I do to solve it?

**EDIT:**

I modified my `CMake` code into:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.6)
project(TrustLineManager)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)

set(BOOST_ROOT "D:/Tools/boost_1_62_0")

set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS ON)
set(Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED ON)

find_package(Boost)
include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_executable(TrustLineManager ${SOURCE_FILES})

target_link_libraries(TrustLineManager Boost::filesystem Boost::thread)
```

I have now this error:

```
Error:Target "TrustLineManager" links to target "Boost::filesystem" but the target was not found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an IMPORTED target, or an ALIAS target is missing?
```

Here is a screenshot of Boost directory contents:

[image]

Comment: Why not following the instructions from the error message? Are you sure that the boost stuff is installed at `C:\MinGW`?

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ cause boost directory does not contains forlders include and lib

Comment: Which CMake version do you have? If it is too old, its "FindBoost.cmake" will not be able to find the latest Boost version. I think that support for Boost 1.62 was introduced only in CMake 3.7 (or maybe CMake 3.6.3).

Answer (score 0):

Obviously CMake finds Boost as it is able to detect its version (1.62.0).

CMake uses the file `FindBoost.cmake` to determine what libraries to link against.
This file is updated continuously when new boost versions appear. 
There, support for Boost 1.62.0 is available only for CMake >= 3.7.0.

So just update your CMake version (or just the file FindBoost.cmake) and you will be fine.

Comment: I'm having the same issue and I have the latest version of CMake (3.9.3). I'm looking for 1.6.5 and when I check FindBoost.cmake I see that 1.6.5 is there... no idea what's going on.